# Toolbar is not displaying on iPhone 8 plus simulator

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I've added a toolbar in `storyboard` and it's well shown. 
However when I run on the simulator (iPhone 8 plus), it doesn't display the toolbar.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you check on other simulators?

Comment: @RajeshKumarR doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Do u have any constraints or other UI that covers tool bar? Or do you have alpha of toolbar set to 0 or color to clear color?
Did you test on other simulators?
Try cleaning the project and reseting the simulator or restarting the simulator.
I just looked over and toolbar is displaying well on iPhone 8 plus simulator and other.
 [image]